# Xamarin.iOS strange behavior for webview showing html5 contain video360

Tags: xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a webview showing URL containing HTML5 content with video 360

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
       
        WKUserContentController userController;

        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
        {
        }

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {
            userController = config.UserContentController;
           
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                Opaque = false;
                Configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
                Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            }
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            ((HybridWebView)Element).InvokeAction(message.Body.ToString());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

I got the video in the middle and when I double click on it
it shows as a separate window and could be closed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry I was mistaken of where to change configurations
it should be like that

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
       
        WKUserContentController userController;
        static WKWebViewConfiguration config = new WKWebViewConfiguration()
        {
            AllowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = false,
            AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true,
            Preferences = new WKPreferences()
            {
                JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true,
                JavaScriptEnabled = true
            }
        };

        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(config)
        {
        }

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {
            userController = config.UserContentController;
           
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                Opaque = false;
                
            }
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            ((HybridWebView)Element).InvokeAction(message.Body.ToString());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```